# RSpec2: Why does should_receive + and_return fail in this test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

This is sort of related to an earlier question I posted, but I think its perplexing enough (IMHO) to justify its own question.

In a nutshell, can anyone help explain why this works / passes:

```
Category.with_parent(@parent_category).should == [@sub_category]
```

while this fails:

```
Category.should_receive(:with_parent).with(@parent_category).and_return([@sub_category])
```

The scope in my Category model is:

```
scope :with_parent, lambda { |parent_id| where(:parent_id => parent_id).order('display_order DESC') }
```

I am using Rails 3.2.12 & RSpec 2, very confused about this one.

Comment: because you're stubbing out the entire scope functionality in the second example. more context needed, but the first thing to check is whether @sub_category is persisted since the first example makes an AR method call that eventually comes down to calling DB.

Comment: @shime, I can confirm "@sub_category" is being persisted to the database. It is created using a FactoryGril.create before each test is run.

Comment: what's the error? is it because you're expecting `Array`, but scope is really returning `ActiveRecord::Relation`?